# Check if appsscript project trigger exists with google sheets formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating apps script triggers that send automated scheduled emails from a google sheets document (document A). I have another document Z where I would like to validate if the trigger was created in the document A apps script environment. Is there a formula or script which helps me with this? I know the name of the apps script project, that contains the trigger.

I have around 200 documents where triggers are created and need a central document to validate if everything went well.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to do it

There is the method `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();` but it only allows you to retrieve the triggers of a certain project, not all triggers on your drive.

### But you can implement a workaround.

E.g., when you create a trigger (I assume you do it programmatically wiht a `triggerBuilder`, [retrieve the trigger Id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger#getuniqueid) and paste it into a speradsheet. If you do it for all triggers you create, you will have a spreadsheet that lists all triggers you created.